# Is there a way to implement single file per commit in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

I have used [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) to implement a logic to allow only one file per commit. It's working fine in the command line and all the on-premise committing.

I need to implement the same logic in Azure Devops user interface using a policy or anything relevant. Is there a way to achieve this?

This is the pre-commit logic I have used locally:

```
- repo: local
  hooks:
    - id: count-committed-files
      name: Count Committed Files
      entry: bash -c 'echo "Number of files: $(git diff --cached --name-only | wc -l)"'
      language: system
      stages: [commit]

    - id: check-file-format
      name: Check File Format
      entry: bash -c 'echo "Running file format check..." && exit 0'  # Replace with your actual command
      language: system
      stages: [commit]
```

Comment: That's a truly bizarre requirement. Why are you concerned abut the number of files being committed?

Comment: Currently, the process we are having require cherry-picking. Want to make sure one commit has one file for easy cherry picking

Comment: @AmilaMGunawardana, may i know if there's any update? If you would like to use pull request policy, you can follow the sample below to get the files number per commit, fail the validation if there are more than 1 file. Please let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to implement the same logic in Azure Devops user interface using a policy or anything relevant. Is there a way to achieve this?

Actually if you directly edit on DevOps website, it's one file per commit already. If you use pull request, you could use branch validation feature in branch policy to check the files in each commit.

Steps:

1. Use rest api [Pull Request Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-commits/get-pull-request-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to get all commitId in pull request.
2. For each commitId, use rest api [Commits - Get Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-changes?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0&tabs=HTTP) to count the file changes.

My PowerShell script to get files count for each commit, you can fail the build once there are two files in one commit.

```
pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Get the list of commits in the pull request
      $url = "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.Name)/pullrequests/$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)/commits?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
      Write-Host $url
      $commits = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"}

      # Check the file count for each commit

      foreach ($commit in $commits.value.CommitId) {
            echo $commit
            $filechangeUrl = "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.Name)/commits/$commit/changes"
            echo $filechangeUrl
            $change = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $filechangeUrl -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"}
            $filesCount = $change.changes.Count
            Write-Host "Commit $commit has $filesCount files."
          }
```

My PR and PipelineResult:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the repo itself?

Comment: You can define it in Pull request branch policy, as you need pull request to complete the code merge, you can `abandon` the merge if the commit has two files.  If you do this in the repo itself, which means the commit has been updated to DevOps branch `already`. The pipeline cannot prevent the update. If pipeline reports there're 2 files in a commit, you need to revert the change on DevOps branch. And the script should be changed as current one is for PR. Do you want to revert the change if pipeline reports it has two files in a commit?

Comment: In a word, CI trigger(checking commit on repo self) cannot prevent code update, just validate if there are 2 or more files in a commit.